# (Angular8) Why click event go to routing '/#'?

Tags: javascript, angular, callback, routes, single-page-application

I wrote this code to use SNS login service. The return callback address from SNS is localhost:4200/account/login. The address is the page on which the current event occurs. The function is declared (click) event in html, and this is in onInit to check callback this.initializeNaver() for declared function.

```
<div id="naverIdLogin" (click)="initializeNaver()">
        <a id="naverIdLogin_loginButton" href="#">
          <img src="../assets/images/icons/naver_login_button.PNG" style="width: 70%; height: 55px">
        </a>
</div>
```

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeNaver();
  }
```

this div button click, go to localhost:4200/#

but initializeNaver() write first line event.preventDefault(), then first click is not working to '#'. second click, working callback function call.

I want to first click, working callback function. please help.

this is function code.

```
 async initializeNaver() {
    event.preventDefault();
     // call naver.com login api sdk lib
     // login success, callbackUrl+param return 
     const naverLogin = await new naver.LoginWithNaverId(
      {
        clientId: "***",
        callbackUrl: "http://localhost:4200/account/login",
        isPopup: false,
        loginButton: {color: "green", type: 3, height: 60},
        callbackHandle: true
      }
    );

    // Invoke int to initialize login information
    naverLogin.init();

    const that = this;
    // login status check
    naverLogin.getLoginStatus(function (status) {
      if (status) {
        const name = naverLogin.user.getName();
        const email = naverLogin.user.getEmail();
        const uniqId = naverLogin.user.getId();
        const key = '';
        that.spinnerService.start();
        that.accountService.naverlogin('', name, email, uniqId, key)
          .subscribe(async (res: IResponse<any>) => {
            if (res.code === RESPONSE_CODE.SUCCESS) {
              that.spinnerService.stop();
              that.sessionService.init(res.data);
              if (that.isRemember) {
                localStorage.setItem('id', that.loginForm.getRawValue().id);
              } else {
                localStorage.removeItem('id');
              }
              that.store.dispatch(new RouterActions.Go({path: ['']}));
            } else if (res.code === RESPONSE_CODE.NAVER_NOT_USER) {
              const login = await that.matDialog.open(AppDialogNaverCertifyComponent, {
                panelClass: 'dialog-confirm-container',
                disableClose: false,
                data: {name: name, email: email, uniqId: uniqId}
              });
              that.spinnerService.stop();
              login.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
                that.store.dispatch(new RouterActions.Go({path: ['']}));
              });
            }
        })

      } else {
        console.log("AccessToken이 올바르지 않습니다.");
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding click event on the anchor tag instead of parent `div` .Your click must be happening on the anchor tag.So it will redirect to href specified.

Other option is add a click on anchor and add `event.preventDefault()` .

eg:

```
 <div id="naverIdLogin" (click)="initializeNaver($event)">
    <a id="naverIdLogin_loginButton" href="#" (click)="preventDefault($event)">
      <img src="../assets/images/icons/naver_login_button.PNG" style="width: 70%; height: 55px">
    </a>
```

You can learn more about `event.preventDeafult` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). 
or  change click event to `a` tag

```
<div id="naverIdLogin" >
    <a id="naverIdLogin_loginButton" href="#" (click)="initializeNaver($event)">
      <img src="../assets/images/icons/naver_login_button.PNG" style="width: 70%; height: 55px">
    </a>
```

Also add

```
async initializeNaver($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();    
       /*Your code here*/
  }
```

Comment: thanks, This method is valid. However, this makes it impossible to refer to ng-onInit. I need this in ng-onInit.

Comment: @박진웅 You can pass $event as null when called from ngOnInit and in function check if event exists and call preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<a id="naverIdLogin_loginButton" href="#">
```

To

```
<a id="naverIdLogin_loginButton">
```

Remove `href="#"`